# How to change pandas display font of index column

Tags: pandas

```
data = {
    'X': [3, 2, 0, 1], 
    'Y': [0, 3, 7, 2]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
df.style.set_properties(**{
    'font-family':'Courier New'
})
df
```

The index column is displayed in bold, is it possible to change font of index column?

Answer (score 0):

You must use `table_styles`. In this example I manage to make the `"font-weight":"normal"` for the index and columns:

Let's define some test data:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4],
                   'B':[5,4,3,1]})
```

We define style customization to use:

```
styles = [
    dict(selector="th", props=[("font-weight","normal"),
                               ("text-align", "center")])]
```

We pass the style variable as the argument for `set_table_styles()`:

```
html = (df.style.set_table_styles(styles))
html
```

And the output is:
[image]

Please feel free to read about the documentation in [pandas Styling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html) for more details.